# Deploy server/client app engine Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I developed React app which the runtime is nodejs and this app contains server/client and I want to deploy it to Google Cloud Platform - App Engine and this is my **package.json** but what is happening is after deployed only the server is deployed and working but the client is not get deployed

```
{
  "name": "newapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my test app",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta.3",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mx-react-components": "^5.1.11",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0-alpha.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

Then I am trying to deploy the app by this Command line

`gcloud app deploy`

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? Looks like "yarn server" and "yarn client" don't work. Because yarn command doesn't exist on the engine